# Display products under Multiselect options

Tags: magento-1.9, module, products, backend

We have around 10 products in one category with **category name as "custom" & id = "40"**

We created some "Brands" [values] in backend.

[image]

Once we click on each brand, it will display like below image:

[image]

In above image, below `Status` field, we want to create a **Multiselect** box [similar like store view] and we want to display those 10 products assigned to category "custom" in multi-select box.

```
app/code/local/Company/Brand/Block/Adminhtml/Item/Edit/Tab/Min.php

<?php
class Company_Brand_Block_Adminhtml_Category_Edit_Tab_Main extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    /**
     * Preparation of current form
     *
     * @return Outthink_Brand_Block_Adminhtml_Category_Edit_Tab_Main
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = Mage::registry('brand_category');

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('brand_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array (
                'legend' => Mage::helper('brand')->__('General information'), 
                'class' => 'fieldset-wide' ));

        if ($model->getCategoryId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('category_id', 'hidden', array (
                    'name' => 'category_id'
            ));
        }



        $fieldset->addField('category_name', 'text', array (
            'name' => 'category_name', 
            'label' => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Category Name'), 
            'title' => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Category Name'), 
            'required' => true,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('cat_order', 'text', array (
            'name' => 'cat_order', 
            'label' => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Category Order'), 
            'title' => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Category Order'), 
            'required' => false,
        ));

        /**
         * Check is single store mode
         */
        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $fieldset->addField('store_id', 'multiselect', 
                    array (
                            'name' => 'store_id[]', 
                            'label' => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Store view'), 
                            'title' => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Store view'), 
                            'required' => true, 
                            'values' => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true) ));
        }
        else {
            $fieldset->addField('store_id', 'hidden', array (
                    'name' => 'store_id[]', 
                    'value' => Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getId() ));
            $model->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getId());
        }

        $fieldset->addField('is_active', 'select', 
                array (
                        'label' => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Status'), 
                        'title' => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Category Status'), 
                        'name' => 'is_active', 
                        'required' => true, 
                        'options' => array (
                                '1' => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Enabled'), 
                                '0' => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Disabled') ) ));

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

I will give 50 bounty points if it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in your form:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(40)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$categorylist = array();
$categorylist[] = array(
    'value' => '', 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Category')
);
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $categorylist[] = array(
        'value' => $product->getEntityId(), 'label' => $product->getName()
    );
}
$fieldset->addField('category', 'multiselect',
    array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Category'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'values' => $categorylist,
        'name' => 'category[]',

    ));
```

Comment: i added like this : http://pasted.co/8d3b5a75 , i added your code below the this line `'0' => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Disabled') ) 
                       ));`

Comment: what is the output it's working?

Comment: sorrry, not working for me

Comment: any error the filed is showing or not?

Comment: no error, it showing same as before.

Comment: i test this code it working perfectly make sure you are editing the right file and refresh your cache.

Comment: i refreshed cache , now this error : `Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Servicecenters_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/html/sbdev2/app/Mage.php on line 547`

Comment: updated the code kindly check and feedback me.

Comment: its working : http://prnt.sc/bvmdlp , when i select product and click on "save", its not saving.

Comment: i didt mentioned in question reagrding saving, i got answer for this. but please help for saving also.

Comment: post new question this question already created the mess. you have to explain how you want save every id differently or on one column.